# I am not able to boot into the Linux i have installed on my second nvme m.2 ssd

Tags: dual-boot, ssd

So i have a laptop with 2 ssds, both of them nvme. i have windows on one of them and have installed parrot OS 5.1 on the second nvme.

whenever i choose the second ssd as my boot device my laptop always boots into the windows.

how can i rectify this or what is the correct way to install it if all else fails

Regards

Comment: Is Grub installed on second ssd ?